# ERROR 000496: table is being edited Failed to execute (AddField), when calculating field inside For Loop with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, error-000496

I have several shapefiles to which I must calculate a new field, so I am using the `arcpy.AddField_management` and `arcpy.CalculateField_management` tool inside a For Loop.
However, the For Loop works only in the first iteration, then I get an error:

```
ERROR 000496: table is being edited Failed to execute (AddField).
```

I understand that it cannot be passed to the next Shapefile because there is an edit session open, I have then tried to [stop and save the edition session](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.7/arcpy/data-access/editor.htm) at the end of each iteration, but I keep getting the same error.

The `For Loop` am trying to perform:

```py
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() #get a list of feature classes
for fc in fcList:  #loop through feature classes
    with arcpy.da.Editor(env.workspace) as edit:
        fieldname = newFname(fc) # Function that looks for the name of the feature and get the pollutant name from it
        arcpy.AddField_management(fc, fieldname, 'FLOAT')
        arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, fieldname, "!grid_code!", "PYTHON3")
    # Stop the edit operation.
    edit.stopOperation()
    # Stop the edit session and save the changes
    edit.stopEditing(True)
```

Comment: It's likely not *your* editing session that's causing the conflict, but someone else's, so formalizing your session isn't going to help. It should be obvious from the directory listing if someone else has the shapefile locked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not need to start an editing session to add and calculate a field.  I just tested this on a couple of shapefiles sitting locally on my laptop and it worked.

```
shapefiles = ["shapefile1", "shapefile2"]

for a in shapefiles:
    arcpy.AddField_management(a, "Foo", "TEXT", "#", "#", 50)
    arcpy.AddField_management(a, "Bar", "TEXT", "#", "#", 50)
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(a, "Foo", '"Test"', "PYTHON_9.3")
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(a, "Bar", '"Test"', "PYTHON_9.3")
```

Comment: Yes @Dan, the editing session was not necessary.
By other hand it wasn't working because the Shapefiles weren't being attached and opened in the content pane.